# Not finding a tag while web scraping in selenium

Tags: python, html

url = https://bvb.ro/FinancialInstruments/Details/FinancialInstrumentsDetails.aspx?s=M

I tried hard but still, I am unable to find a 'strong tag' in my HTML.[image]
The image shown is the text on the website I want to extract.
Help, please.

the error I am getting is - nonetype object

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver',options=option)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch')
time.sleep(5)
html_text3 = driver.page_source
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(html_text3,'lxml')
data3 = soup3.find("strong")
print(data3)
```

Comment: The URL in the code doesn't match the URL at the start of the question

Comment: to make it short take a look at your soup3 result, there you will see that the site blocks the access. I guess they dont like scrapers to automate accessing data. since i dont spend time on selenium, there you might be able to set a user agent so the server side code isnt acting up

Comment: if you run it without the headless option you will get your strong tag but also the browser opening the website

Answer (score 0):

well if you not depending on selenium the rerquests package can help out.

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html_text3 = requests.get('https://bvb.ro/FinancialInstruments/Details/FinancialInstrumentsDetails.aspx?s=M')
time.sleep(5)

soup3 = BeautifulSoup(html_text3.text,'html.parser')
data3 = soup3.find("strong")
print(data3)
```

this should give you this

```
<strong class="value">17.4000</strong>
```

cheers

Markus

Comment: Thanks ,that worked . Cn you tell me weather I can scrap data from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/WRD.PA?p=WRD.PA&.tsrc=fin-srch using beautifulsoup only?

Comment: if `requests.get` gives you back well formed HTML then beautifulsoup should be able to parse it.